# SQL DataType Negative Decimal

Tags: sql, decimal, sqldatatypes

Im inserting Data into a database, they have a decimal and a negative number, is there a way to the DataType Decimal into negative numbers or is there another data type I can use?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with negative decimal values but I think your question perhaps needs some clarification. What is it precisely that you'd like to do?

Answer (score 25):

The `decimal` datatype can store negative numbers as well.  So to answer your question, yes you can use the `decimal` datatype to store negative decimal numbers.

Here is some proof:

```
create table NegativeDecimal
(
    somedec decimal(10, 4) not null
)
go

insert into negativedecimal
select -12.3
union all
select 16.4
go

select *
from NegativeDecimal

somedec
---------------------------------------
-12.3000
16.4000

(2 row(s) affected)
```

EDIT:  This is provided you are using SQL Server.  Please specify your RDBMS.

Answer (score 5):

You don't state which DBMS you're using, but on MySQL at least, negatives are supported in decimals:

```
mysql> create table x (x decimal(5,2));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into x (x) values (-3.14);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from x;
+-------+
| x     |
+-------+
| -3.14 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

For math definition decimal number could be positive or negative and the data structures know that, for the same reason is not a special type for negative or positive numbers